# Combine all values per key after accumulating data from all nodes using CombineFn

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to iterate through values of KV pCollection on perKey basis. I used below code to combine using custom class,

```
PCollection<KV<String, String>> combinesAttributes =
              valExtract.get(extAttUsers).apply(Combine.<String, String>perKey(
                      new CombineAttributes()));
```

And below is my custom combine class,

```
public static class CombineAttributes implements SerializableFunction<Iterable<String>, String> {
   @Override
   public String apply(Iterable<String> input) {...}..}
```

This was working fine for small inputs but for large inputs the combine was not as expected. The output had combined only few values for a key, others were missing. I was assuming that the output had only combined data from one node.

The documentation in https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/combine mentions to use CombineFn in order to combine full collection-of-values per key in all nodes.

But when I changed the custom combine function as below, I am getting following error,

```
incompatible types: CombineAttributes cannot be converted to com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.SerializableFunction<java.lang.Iterable<java.lang.String>,java.lang.String>
```

**Combine function**

```
public static class CombineAttributes extends CombineFn<Iterable<String>, CombineAttributes.Accum, String> {

public static class Accum {
  List<String> inputList = new ArrayList<String>();
}
public Accum createAccumulator() { return new Accum(); }
public Accum addInput(Accum accum, Iterable<String> input) {
  for (String item : input) {
    accum.inputList.add(item);
  }
  return accum;
}
public Accum mergeAccumulators(Iterable<Accum> accums) {
   Accum merged = createAccumulator();
   for (Accum accum : accums) {
     for (String item : accum.inputList) {
       merged.inputList.add(item);
     }
   }
   return merged;
 }
 public String extractOutput(Accum accum) {
   return "";
 }
}
```

There was no sample code available for combine perKey extending `CombineFn`. Please let me know what is wrong with the code above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to iterate through all the values you can use `GroupByKey` to turn a `PCollection<KV<K, V>>` into `PCollection<KV<K, Iterable<V>>`. Then you can write a `DoFn` that processes each element of that, and inside iterate over the `Iterable<V>`.

Note that you'll only receive all values associated with a key in the same window. If you're using the default global window, that will be all values.

---

`Combine` and `CombineFn` are most useful when you want to combine all the values into a smaller output. For instance, if you want to take the sum or mean of all the values it will be more efficient to do so using `Sum.perKey()` or `Mean.perKey()`. The efficiency comes from being able to pass around (and merge) accumulators. In the case of `Sum`, this corresponds to a partial sum.

As an example, say the pipeline runs on two machines. The first machine processes `KV<user1, attr1a>, KV<user1, attr1b>, KV<user2, attr2a>` and the second machine processes `KV<user1, attr1c>, KV<user2, attr2b>`.

The `CombineAttributes` (either way it was implemented) would first be invoked on each machine. So it could combine `[attr1a, attr1b]` into a single string or accumulator (say `attr1a+attr1b`). Then it would run on the other machine to combine `[attr1c]` to `attr1c`. Then it would merge all of these partial results to get a final accumulator -- `attr1a+attr1b+attr1c`. In the case of the original implementation, that would be the final answer. In the latter, `extractOutput` would be called on this accumulator.